# Python + Leopard + Fink + Mac Ports + Python.org + Idiot = broken Python - fresh start?

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-install

I have been enjoying learning the basics of python, but before I started reading things I tried to install various python versions and modules clumsily. Now that I have some ideas of what I want to do and how to do it I'm finding that various aspects are broken. For instance, 2.6 IDLE won't launch, and when I try to import modules they usually don't work.

My question is, how would you recommend I clean this up and start fresh? I have read information about modifying the 2.6 install, but I still can't get it to work.

IDLE 2.4 works, and when I launch python from the terminal I am running python 2.4.4.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem so much when I first got my Mac. The best solution I found was to delete everything I'd installed and just go with the [pythonmac.org](http://pythonmac.org) version of Python (2.6). I then installed setuptools from the same site, and then used easy_install to install every other package.

Oh, and I got the GNU C Compiler from the Xcode developer tools CD (which you can download from Apple's website), so that I can compile C extensions.

Comment: dbr has further input on cleaning up the .profile (your environment's PATH and MANPATH variables).

Answer (score 1):

Macports should be easy to get rid of; just delete /opt/local/. I think that Fink does something similar.

You can do `which python` to see what python is the default one. The system python should be in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python

The MacPython you may have downloaded would either be in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework. You can delete this as well.

Also, both MacPython and MacPorts edit your ~/.profile and change the PYTHONPATH, make sure to edit it and remove the extra paths there.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to start afresh with Mac Ports or Fink is to simply remove the folder `/sw/` (for fink) or `/opt/` for MacPorts.

To completely remove them, you will have to remove a line in your `~/.profile` file:

For fink:

```
test -r /sw/bin/init.sh && . /sw/bin/init.sh
```

..and for MacPorts, I don't have it installed currently, but there will be something along the lines of:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/sbin
```

---

As for installing Python, currently the cleanest way is to build it from source..

I wrote up how I installed Python 2.6 on Leopard [here](http://neverfear.org/blog/view/Installing_Python_2_6_3_0_without_breaking_stuff/). It was for one of the 2.6 beta releases, so change the `curl -O` line to the newest release!

In short, download and extract the latest [python 2.6 source tarball](http://python.org/ftp/python/2.6/Python-2.6.tgz), then (in a terminal) `cd` to where you extracted the tarball, and run the following commands..

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python2.6
make
sudo make install
```

That will install python2.6 into `/usr/local/python2.6/` (the last line requires sudo, so will ask you for your password)

Finally add `/usr/local/python2.6` to $PATH, by adding the following line you the file `~/.profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/python2.6
```

Then you will be able to run the `python2.6` command.

Ideally you would just install [MacPython](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/Leopard), but it doesn't seem to have a decent Python 2.6 installer yet.